# What does Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress mean?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am setting the DataContext of an object in the completed method of a background worker thread. For some reason, I get an error saying:

Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress pointing to the Chart1.DataContext=allDates line.

What does a tree walk is in progress mean? I've tried doing this set using a Dispatcher operation as well and that gives the same error... Any ideas? Google yeilds nothing on this error message.

The code taht's causing this is internal to Microsoft's Charting toolkit... I wonder if I've found a bug in their control...

Without Dispatcher:

```
 void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ArticlesPerTimePeriodResult result = (ArticlesPerTimePeriodResult)e.Result;
        lvArticles.ItemsSource = result.DatesOfArticles;


        Chart1.DataContext = result.AllDates;
    }
```

With Dispatcher:

```
 void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ArticlesPerTimePeriodResult result = (ArticlesPerTimePeriodResult)e.Result;
        lvArticles.ItemsSource = result.DatesOfArticles;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>>>)(delegate(List<KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>> allDates)
        {
            Chart1.DataContext = allDates;
        }), result.AllDates);

        //Chart1.DataContext = result.AllDates;
    }
```

Error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  Message="Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at NewsCluesWpf.App.Main() in C:\SoftwareInstall\VSProjects\NewsClues\NewsCluesWpf\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message="Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress."
       Source="PresentationFramework"
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
            at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.InsertInternal(Int32 index, UIElement element)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ObservableCollectionListAdapter`1.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OnCollectionChanged>b__0(T item, Int32 index)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.EnumerableFunctions.ForEachWithIndex[T](IEnumerable`1 that, Action`2 action)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ObservableCollectionListAdapter`1.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.AggregatedObservableCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ChildCollectionCollectionChanged>b__f(ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1 that)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1.Mutate(Action`1 action)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.AggregatedObservableCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass14.<ChildCollectionCollectionChanged>b__e(T item, Int32 index)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.EnumerableFunctions.ForEachWithIndex[T](IEnumerable`1 that, Action`2 action)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.AggregatedObservableCollection`1.ChildCollectionCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.AddAxisToChartArea(Axis axis)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.ActualAxesCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.UniqueObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.GetAxes(DataPoint firstDataPoint, Func`2 independentAxisPredicate, Func`1 independentAxisFactory, Func`2 dependentAxisPredicate, Func`1 dependentAxisFactory)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.AreaSeries.GetAxes(DataPoint firstDataPoint)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.GetAxes()
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.OnDataPointsChanged(IList`1 newDataPoints, IList`1 oldDataPoints)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSingleSeriesWithAxes.OnDataPointsChanged(IList`1 newDataPoints, IList`1 oldDataPoints)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineAreaBaseSeries`1.OnDataPointsChanged(IList`1 newDataPoints, IList`1 oldDataPoints)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.LoadDataPoints(IEnumerable newItems, IEnumerable oldItems)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.Refresh()
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
            at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Invalidate(Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
            at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnInheritablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, InheritablePropertyChangeInfo info)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
            at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
            at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnInheritablePropertyChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, InheritablePropertyChangeInfo info, Boolean skipStartNode)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_DataContext(Object value)
            at NewsCluesWpf.ArticlesPerDay.<bg_RunWorkerCompleted>b__1(List`1 allDates) in C:\SoftwareInstall\VSProjects\NewsClues\NewsCluesWpf\ArticlesPerDay.xaml.cs:line 72
       InnerException:
```

Comment: I believe the completed portion of the background worker call is done on the calling thread, not the background thread, so you shouldn't need a dispatcher, unless the calling thread itself was not the UI thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After playing around more, I think this is a bug in the Silverlight charting toolkit.

The following code causes a reproduceable crash.

```
int runCount = 0;
        private void bindChart(string searchString)
        {
           List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> dataEmpty = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();

            List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> dataFilled = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
            dataFilled.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Today, 1));
            if (runCount == 0)
            {
                Chart1.DataContext= dataEmpty;
            }
            else
            {
                Chart1.DataContext = dataFilled;
            }
            runCount++;

        }
```

XAML:

```
<charting:Chart Grid.Row="0"
    Title="Title"
    LegendTitle="Legend" Name="Chart1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <charting:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"

                                       DependentValuePath="Value"

                                       IndependentValuePath="Key"

                                       Background="Red" />


        </charting:Chart>
```

This will fail on the second call to bindChart.

Comment: I filed a bug on CodePlex. It turns out this is a bug in the chart framework. See http://silverlight.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=3258

 There is a workaround. Set teh chart's DataPointSeries Items source instead of the data context:                 
       (Chart1.Series[0] as DataPointSeries).ItemsSource = dataEmpty;

Comment: This fix also works for WPF in VS2013. Personally I'm adhering to MVVM so I created a behaviour with a dependency property that I bind to the DataContext. The change handler for this DP then assigns it to the series with "((d as MyChartBehavior).AssociatedObject as DataPointSeries).ItemsSource = e.NewValue as IEnumerable;"

Answer (score 10):

**SOLVED!**

The problem: I want to update my chart on the GUI every time some data is changed.

```
 myChart.DataContext = MTFdata;
```

when i do this i gett the error:  Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress

How I solved it:

Insted of this:

```
 <chartingToolkit:LineSeries   DependentValuePath="Key" 
                                                    IndependentValuePath="Value" 
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                                    IsSelectionEnabled="False"
                                                                             >
```

Use This:

```
 <chartingToolkit:LineSeries   DependentValuePath="Key" 
                                                    IndependentValuePath="Value" 
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                                    DataContext="{Binding}"
                                                    IsSelectionEnabled="False"
                                                                             >
```

Use both `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and `DataContext="{Binding}"`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Hej,

I've just had the error, and fixed it as well.
The error also accoured when setting the datacontext.

I found that I had a selectionchanged-subscription on the list that was having its datacontext set. In this selectionchanged i was altering another property with notification support, which had a visual element binding on it.

Solved the problem by using the dispatcher for setting the property.

So try look for subscriptions on changes...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some operation is being made that is changing a collection while it's being used. That's a big no-no.

Without analyzing the code further, that's all I can say.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is my research on it.](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/03/cannot-modify-logical-children-for-this.html)

[Mirror of said link on WaybackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109031707/http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/03/cannot-modify-logical-children-for-this.html).

It is a WPF Exception thrown by Add/RemoveLogicalChild methods in FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement when a tree walk is in progress. The boring details of it are in the blog post, but the bottom line is that you can't do more than test for it then catch it where it occurs. The exception should be a relatively rare occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resetting `DataContext` reusing via observable collection also works...

```
    int runCount = 0;

    private void bindChart()
    {
        ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> data = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();

        if (runCount == 0)
        {
            this.DataContext = dataEmpty;
        }
        else
        {
            var de = this.DataContext as ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>;
            de.Clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < (new Random(DateTime.Now.Second)).Next(100); i++)
            {
                de.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i), i));
            }
        }

        runCount++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with the WPF charting toolkit. Everyone said not to bind to the DataContext and bind directly to the ItemsSource but I already was binding to the ItemsSource and still got the error. In my case I was binding to the `SelectedItem` of a ListBox or TreeView. The only thing I could get to work was to manually bind to the `ItemsSource` when the SelectedItemChanged() event fires.

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (TreeView.SelectedItem != null)
        LineSeries.ItemsSource = (TreeView.SelectedItem as MyObject).Items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when a parent control (AvalonDock) triggered the child user control to reload: the user control would fire its "Loaded" event and my application would crash.

I removed the Loaded event handler from the user control and used the Initialized event instead. That fixed my problem although I'm not totally sure why.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I am not using any background threads though. I just have a slider and on the ValueChanged event for the slider, I am recalculating and resetting the DataContext.

For example, A burn down chart. As the initial value changes, the graph updates automatically (essentially the Y axis of line series).

Changing the datacontext worked in the beta version of silverlight 3. Doesn't work in the release version. The above comment about setting (Chart1.Series[0] as DataPointSeries).ItemsSource works for me

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment why you down voted a post from nearly 4 years ago?