# Update LineGraph Every Second

Tags: wpf, vb.net, charts

Hi I'm trying to update a line chart every second (from the wpf data visualisation toolkit). The following code works for a PieChart:

VB:

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    '  DispatcherTimer setup
    Dim dt As DispatcherTimer = New DispatcherTimer()
    AddHandler dt.Tick, AddressOf dispatcherTimer_Tick
    dt.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    dt.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub dispatcherTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    UpadateChartData()
    Chart1.DataContext = ""
    Chart1.DataContext = ChartData
End Sub

Public Sub UpadateChartData()
    Dim r As Integer = GetRandom(1, 10)
    ChartData.Add(New ChartData() With {.Name = r.ToString, .Votes = r})
End Sub
```

XAML:

```
 <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="Chart1" Title="Chart1" Width="400" Height="400" >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Votes}" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

But I get this error when I use LineSeries (or any other type of chart):

> Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the error or suggest an alternative approach?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992241/what-does-cannot-modify-the-logical-children-for-this-node-at-this-time-because-a)

Comment: It appears that this is a bug in the Toolkit charts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992241/what-does-cannot-modify-the-logical-children-for-this-node-at-this-time-because-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed appears to be a bug in the toolkit, as ColinE mentioned.

I would suggest to take a look at [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/), which really facilitates these kind of things and makes it very easy. They provide a few new objects like `ObservableDataSource<T>`, and on this you can call `source.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, T)` which will update the graph.

Comment: Roel, thanks for pointing me towards an alternative to the broken WPF charting!