# Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I have two wpf tool kit charts one is pie chart and second bar series

i have method which i call only on form load

```
 chartGuest.DataContext = null;
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
            HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();

            var _RoomTypes = (from d in db.roomtypes select d.roomtype1).ToList();
            var _RoomTypeID = (from d in db.roomtypes select d.id).ToList();
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < _RoomTypeID.Count; i++)
            {
                count = Convert.ToInt32((from d in db.actions where d.room.roomtypeid == _RoomTypeID[i] select d.id).Count());
                valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(_RoomTypes[i], count));

            }
            chartGuest.DataContext = valueList;
```

It gaves such error : Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress.

The same code works great on pie series chart.

This is my charts:

```
 <charting:Chart x:Name="chartRoomType" Width="402" Height="255" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,275,0,0">
            <charting:Chart.Series>
                <charting:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" Title="Room Types" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
            </charting:Chart.Series>
                    </charting:Chart>
                    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,292,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"  />
                    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,296,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Room Types" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <charting:Chart x:Name="chartGuest" Height="269" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="6,0" Title="Guests">
                            <charting:Chart.Series>
                                <charting:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" Title="Room Types" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
                            </charting:Chart.Series>
                        </charting:Chart>
```

Can anyone help me?
P.s. i found this question but it was unhelpful 
[What does Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992241/what-does-cannot-modify-the-logical-children-for-this-node-at-this-time-because-a)

Comment: Use the workaround described in the comment on the accepted answer to the question you linked.  It is also described in this bug report: [Chart throws exception when bound to an empty datasource and then to a populated datasource](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/3258?ProjectName=silverlight).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992241/what-does-cannot-modify-the-logical-children-for-this-node-at-this-time-because-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use DataPointSeries.ItemsSource to bind to the data context.**

Assuming that this is XAML of your your window panel that has the datagrid and charting control sharing a common list as `ItemsSource`..

```
  <StackPanel>
    <tk:DataGrid MaxHeight="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 IsReadOnly="True">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Key"
                                   Binding="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                                   Binding="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>

    <charting:Chart MaxHeight="300"
                    Title="Title"
                    LegendTitle="Legend"
                    Name="Chart1">
        <charting:AreaSeries DependentValuePath="Value"
                             IndependentValuePath="Key"
                             Background="Red" >
            <charting:DataPointSeries.ItemsSource>
                <Binding BindsDirectlyToSource="True"/>
            </charting:DataPointSeries.ItemsSource>
        </charting:AreaSeries>
    </charting:Chart>

    <Button Content="Change DataGrid and Chart Data" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind we reset the data context of the window ....

```
    private List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list1;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        var random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, random.Next()));
        }

        this.DataContext = list1;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, random.Next()));
        }

        this.DataContext = list1;
    }
```

Everytime you click the button the chart refreshes without error.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: How this can help me? when i call this method its go this.DataContext = dataEmpty; here and my chart will not fill with values and if i call it again its give same error. how this must help me?

Comment: OK my bad ... `dataEmpty` should be `data` ... see my edited answer above ... and if you have followed this exactly how its shown above then it stops giving the error you are getting.  Coz it was giving me the same error when I had set the `DataContext`, but when I reuse the same data cotext and `Clear` and `Add` to it it works!

Comment: Not it does not work too coz i have datagrid same window and when use this  this.DataContext = data; my grid is clearing. Beside this i have many charts in this window

Comment: @Acid, thats what I am saying. DataGrid or any other Grid control works and does not throw this error. But Chart control does. And in my case it gave that error too. But when I keep the reference of the bound observable collection as it is and **reused** it by clearing and adding new items it worked. Probably if you post more code it can help me understand what error you are exactly getting.

Comment: I have window where is datagrid and 3 charts two bar and 1 pie i want to take values from observable collection which is data context of datagrid and than bind it charts . If i use your code datagrid will clear and another charts change values

Comment: **For this, see my edited reply above.** ... I got what you are saying. You are **sharing** the same collection across multiple itemssources such as several charts and datagrid. Hence you cannot clear and add to it. My latest solution employs `DataPointSeries.ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same exception in different situation. I work with code which takes collection of existing UIElements and create new UIElement and set first one as Content of second one. Aditionally, it takes property value from existing UIElement and set it as value of different property of new UIElement.

```
foreach(UIElement insideElement in uiElementCollection)
{
    var outsideElement = new TabItem
    {
         Content = insideElement
         ,Header = insideElement.Title
    }
}
```

But in this case Title of inside property can be a Binding, but code above copies only value and when insideElement.Title is bounded to some source, outsideElement.Header doesn't reflect change.
So I changed code to bind HeaderProperty to TitleProperty of insideElement:

```
foreach(UIElement insideElement in uiElementCollection)
{
    var outsideElement = new TabItem
    {
         Content = insideElement
    }

    outsideElement.SetBinding(HeaderedContentControl.HeaderProperty,
                        new Binding
                        {
                            Source = insideElement,
                            Path = new PropertyPath(MyUIElement.TitleProperty)
                        });
}
```

But when I executed code above, I received

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress.

I found that I can't bind one dependency property to another one, which is stored inside Content property.

I tried to get binding expression of innerUIElement and set it as new binding to HeaderProperty of outsideUIElement.

```
foreach(UIElement insideElement in uiElementCollection)
{
    var outsideElement = new TabItem
    {
         Content = insideElement
    }

    BindingExpression titleBindingExpression = pageControl.GetBindingExpression(MyUIElement.TitleProperty);
        if (titleBindingExpression != null)
            {                            
                tabItem.SetBinding(HeaderedContentControl.HeaderProperty, new Binding { Source = titleBindingExpression.DataItem, Path = titleBindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path });

            }
            else
            {
                tabItem.Header = innerUIElement.Title;
            }
}
```

Now, outer UI Element is binded to same source and WPF presenter doesn't throw Exception. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but in case anyone else comes across it I found another way around it.  Put the chart into a StackPanel, created with Visibility of "Collapsed" ("Hidden" DOES NOT WORK).  Then set visibility to "Visible" after setting DataContext the first time (I'm doing it every time, but after the first it's redundant).

My experience agrees with reports I've seen that the problem is a bug that occurs when setting a non-empty DataContext after having had an empty one; but apparently it doesn't do the "tree walk" if the chart is collapsed.